# VS2013 Hangs when Adding UserControl to Form

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2013, user-controls, c++-cli, freeze

The best way to explain this is to describe how I can reproduce the problem at will.

1. Open an existing Windows Form file in the designer
2. Open the toolbox and click a custom UserControl
3. Click in the form in the designer to add it
4. VS2013 hangs (does NOT crash); kill VS2013 and relaunch it
5. Open the form again
6. Reset the toolbox and re-add the DLL that contains my custom UserControls
7. Try adding the control to the form--it works just fine!
8. Close VS2013
9. Open VS2013
10. Repeat the task of adding the custom UserControl to a form
11. VS2013 hangs

So, the moral of the story is that after closing and reopening VS2013, any attempt to add a custom usercontrol will hang VS2013, and the only way to remedy it is to reset the toolbox and re-add the usercontrol DLL; that remedy only lasts until VS2013 is exited and launched again.

Lots of googling has yielded suggestions regarding using a second VS instance to attach to the first and see the exception that is thrown, but there's no exception being thrown; the application just hangs.

The one thing I found that most-closely described my issue turned out to be related to some remote-desktop software that I'm not using.

Anybody got any ideas?  I haven't tried reinstalling Visual Studio, as that represents a fairly significant amount of down-time.  Last resort sort of thing (and I've read some things that indicated it won't be helpful).

Edit: Apparently sometimes the reset/re-add **doesn't** make it better.

Edit: Some additional things I should have mentioned:

- There is no devenv.exe when I try to use a second VS instance to
  debug, so I end up choosing WDExpress.exe
- The particular user control is mature and has not changed recently, and is in use on many forms in the project
- The issue *only* occurs when adding a new instance of the control; the hang does *not* occur simply by attempting to launch the designer for a form that already contains one.
- The latest VS2013 update *may* have fixed it; it's not happening right now and I don't want to anger the gods by trying to reproduce it again until I get my work done.

Comment: Er, my tested-working bounty comment means I test the solution and it works...not that the answerer somehow has to test my code :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to have vanished subsequent to updating VS2013 to **12.0.40629.0 Update 5**, found by selecting *TOOLS* > *Extensions and Updates*, then selecting *Updates* on the left.

It may not work in all cases of seemingly-inexplicable UserControl-incited hangs in the Designer, but it seemed to solve the problem for me.  I'm putting this here (rather than deleting the question) in case my experience can help someone else.

Answer (score 2):

Hanging Visual Studio with a custom UserControl is *very* easy to do.  A simple example is all it takes, double-click the design surface and write:

```
    private void UserControl1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        while (true) { }
    }
```

Compile and drop the added control from the top of the toolbox and drop it on a form.  Show is over.

You probably did not spend enough time using the guidance you already found or we'd have a stack trace to look at.  Attaching a debugger is easy enough and you'd be ahead if the code throws an exception.  But it doesn't, a hang like this doesn't throw.  Exercise debugging this particular simple hang to find out how to do it:

- Start VS again, Debug > Attach to Process > select devenv.exe
- Important: click the Select button above the process list.  You'll need to select the "Debug these code types" radio button and tick "Managed (v4.5, v4.0)" as well as "Native".  Now click Attach.
- Give it time to load the symbol files, takes quite a while, especially if that was never done before.
- Use Debug > Break All.
- If you are *lucky* then it now stops on the exact statement that causes the hang.  Likely in this case.  This is however *not* guaranteed, it might also break on one of the many threads that are running inside devenv.exe, which ever happened to be active at the exact moment the debugger broke in.
- In which case you need to use Debug > Windows > Threads to select the thread on which the UserControl code is running.  Should be the one labeled "Main Thread".  Double-click it.
- If the editor doesn't switch to the source code file with the hang then use Debug > Windows > Call Stack to get insight in how the hang occurred.  Update the question with that trace if you need more help.

In general, prime candidates for code in your UserControl that can cause the hang are its constructor, its Load event and its Paint event.  Use the [DesignMode property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.component.designmode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to bypass dangerous code that is not likely to work well when it runs inside the designer instead of the regular process.  And beware of the chicken-and-egg problem, if you have a plain bug in your UserControl then it can easily strike first at design time, before you get a chance to debug it like you normally would.  Disabling chunks of code may be necessary to increment towards the bug, use DesignMode to get there.

One more detail, this is tagged [c++-cli].  You must select the old debugging engine to debug C++/CLI code.  Tools > Options > Debugging > General > tick the "Use Managed Compatibility Mode" checkbox.

Comment: devenv.exe isn't an option when trying to connect a second instance's debugger.  I should have mentioned that.  So I connected to WDExpress.exe.

Comment: I should also add that this is a mature custom UserControl that has not changed recently and is used on a lot of existing forms.  The hang ONLY occurs when adding one; not when designing an existing form which contains one.

Comment: These comments are very unhelpful to move this Q+A forward.  If you just want to throw your hands in the air and exclaim "VS bug!" then lets not bother with this.  Show us the stack trace.

Comment: Any advice on how to get a stack trace when you've given me instructions that I **cannot follow because they are inaccurate** would be appreciated.

Comment: Everything I've seen so far talks about attaching to devenv.exe.  **There is no devenv.exe process** listed either in the Windows Task Manager or in the selector within VS, regardless of what "Debug these code types" I've selected.

Comment: @HansPassant: 
Excellent writeup -- I had no idea this was possible.  This helped me fix my custom control.

BrianA.Henning: 
Not that you care anymore but perhaps helpful for future reference and other readers:
You must open another instance of Visual Studio -- shift click your Visual Studio icon on the task bar and you should get another one open... then you will see the process "devenv.exe" in that instance as you follow the instructions.